# tcp server/client using openSSL

Tags: c, linux, openssl

I am trying to use tcp server/client here : https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Simple_TLS_Server
openssl crt and key generation may be okay and socket connection okay too.
I use fork() process to communicate server and client at same time.
but inputed data are not transported or correctly.
I don't know how can i revise it. please help me.

Here is my code.

> Server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

int create_socket(int port)
{
    int s;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (s < 0) {
        perror("Unable to create socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
        perror("Unable to bind");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (listen(s, 1) < 0) {
        perror("Unable to listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return s;
}

void init_openssl()
{
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();
}

void cleanup_openssl()
{
    EVP_cleanup();
}

SSL_CTX *create_context()
{
    const SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    method = SSLv23_server_method();

    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    if (!ctx) {
        perror("Unable to create SSL context");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return ctx;

void configure_context(SSL_CTX *ctx)
{
    SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(ctx, 1);

    /* Set the key and cert */
    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "server.crt", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "server.key", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 ) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int sock;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    init_openssl();
    ctx = create_context();

    configure_context(ctx);

    sock = create_socket(4433);

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    const char reply[] = "test\n";
    char message[BUFSIZ];
    char storedValue[1024];
    int bytes;
    int len = sizeof(addr);

    pid_t pid;

    int client = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);

    if (client < 0) {
        perror("Unable to accept");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    /* Handle connections */
    printf("Talk Server accept new request\n");

    pid = fork();

    while(1) {

    SSL *ssl;
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, client);

        if (SSL_accept(ssl) <= 0) {
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        }

        if (pid < 0) {
                printf("Fork error!\n");
        } else if (pid==0) {
                if((bytes = SSL_read(ssl, message, strlen(message)) != 0)) {
                        printf("Received : %s\n", message);
                        message[0] = '\0';
                        break;
                }
        } else {
                if(fgets(message, BUFSIZ, stdin) != NULL) {
                        SSL_write(ssl, message, strlen(message));
                        message[0] = '\0';
                }
        }

        SSL_shutdown(ssl);
        SSL_free(ssl);
        close(client);

    }

    close(sock);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    cleanup_openssl();
}
```

> Client

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#define IPADDR "127.0.0.1"

int connect_socket(int port)
{
    int c;
    struct sockaddr_in c_addr;

    c = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    memset(&c_addr, 0, sizeof(c_addr));
    c_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    c_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    c_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IPADDR); // 소켓초기화

    if (c < 0) {
        perror("Unable to create socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (connect(c, (struct sockaddr *) &c_addr, sizeof(c_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("Unable to connect123");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return c;
}

void init_openssl()
{
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();
}

void cleanup_openssl()
{
    EVP_cleanup();
}

SSL_CTX *create_context()
{
    const SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    method = SSLv23_client_method(); // SSL 인증서 생성 및 연결


    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    if (!ctx) {
        perror("Unable to create SSL context");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return ctx;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int sock, port;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    init_openssl();

    pid_t pid;

    ctx = create_context();

    // configure_context(ctx);

    printf("PORT NUMBER : ");
    scanf("%d", &port);

    sock = connect_socket(port);
    pid = fork();

    char storedValue[1024];
    char message[BUFSIZ];
    int bytes;

    /* Handle connections */
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    while(1) {

        SSL *ssl;
        ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
        SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock);

        if (SSL_connect(ssl) <= 0) {
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        }

        if(pid==0) {
                bytes = SSL_read(ssl, message, strlen(message));
                fgets(message, BUFSIZ, stdin);
            // storedValue[bytes] = 0;
                printf("Received : %s\n", storedValue);
        }
        else {
                if(fgets(message, BUFSIZ, stdin) != NULL){
                        SSL_write(ssl, message, strlen(message));
                        message[0] = '\0';
                }
        }

        SSL_free(ssl);
        close(sock);
    }
    close(sock);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
}
```

Comment: When you say "inputed data are not transported or correctly", what do you mean by that? What happens when you try to run the programs? What *is* "transported"? What is supposed to be "transported"? Please [edit] your question to elaborate, give us more details. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: If you want to solve a network programming problem, you may need to use wireshark or tcpdump, they can help you a lot. And the data you get from these tools are needed when asking some question like this here. Since it is really important.

Comment: A couple of things though: What is the *string length* of `message` when you call `SSL_read`? Perhaps you meant to use `sizeof message` instead? And as the client doesn't send the string null-terminator, you need to explicitly add it to `message` in the correct position.

Comment: thanks. i may solve it. and thank for your advice, too.